# How does a Colpitts oscillator work? Why is RFC used?

Tags: transistors, oscillator, oscillation

[image]

I want to know the initial flow of signal in this oscillator circuit.

I got confused by the use of RFC and capacitor as RFC blocks the AC signals and allows only DC signal and a capacitor blocks the  DC signal and allows only AC signal.  Can someone please explain how the oscillator works?

If someone knows a good resource to study about LC oscillators please provide a link.

Comment: "RFC"  probably means "radio frequency choke."  The symbol you have shown is for an inductor.  A choke is an inductor.

Comment: RFC is required to fix the DC operating point, aka. bias, of the transistor.

Understanding such circuits is often easier if you first try to understand the DC behavior. You remove all capacitors and replace Induktors by wires. What's left is a biased A amplifier, the gain stage of the oscillator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator

Comment: Flyby comment, it increases the DC quiescent or standing current and therefore improves oscillator linearity.  Most good text books cover oscillators, but I like amature radio resources for this topic.  Here's one of the better ones: https://archive.org/details/SolidStateDesignForTheRadioAmateur1986.  See chapter 2 for intuition related to your question.

Answer (score 2):

> RFC blocks the AC signals and allows only DC signal and a capacitor
> blocks the DC signal and allows only AC signal.

Blocking and allowing "signals" may be problematic. The purpose of the RFC is to look like a high impedance to alternating currents, but have a low impedance to DC currents. 
When AC current is *blocked* from **Vcc**, then AC currents can only go to \$C_c\$...that is its desired purpose.

So as far as *current* is concerned, the RFC does block the alternating signal. As far as *voltage* is concerned, the alternating voltage at transistor collector is free. So signal path is directed from transistor collector through \$C_c\$ to the frequency-determining resonator consisting of *L, C1, C2*.

The "blocking/allowing" rule doesn't really apply to L, C1, C2. These components trade signal current and voltage back and forth between each other in a manner somewhat analogous to an hourglass: https://www.123rf.com/photo_131680287_hourglass-on-white-background-sandglass-3d-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "initial flow"? Perhaps the signal flow within the closed loop ?

Each working oscillator needs a feedback loop which must satisfy **Barkhausens oscillation condition:**

**Loop gain** with **unity magnitude** (in practice slightly larger) and **zero phase** (identical to 360 deg) at the desired oscillation frequency. This is the task of the feedback circuitry (consisting of C1, C2 and L).

The element in the collector path (RFC) can be an additional inductor or a resistor. This element is responsible for the signal gain of the transistor.

Because the transistor stage is an inverting one (common emitter) the feedback path must introduce another 180deg phase shift. This is accomplished by a **third-order lowpass in classical ladder topolgy: r_out-C1-L-C2.**

Here the resistance r_out is the output resistance available at the collector node. The capacitors Cc and Cb are (large) coupling capacitors without any influence on the oscillation condition.

Answer (score 0):

> How does a Colpitts oscillator work?

Note that this can be a bit complicated ... sometimes.
Only see, for now, these two pictures (only change of inductor).
Simulated with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip).

[image]

[image]